# How to overwrite Bootstrap's checkbox with an emoji?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

As described in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/ what Bootstrap allows me to do is change the checkmark with a link like so:
`$form-check-input-checked-bg-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/x/U/Z/k/S/7/custom-check-mark.svg");`

What I want to do is use an emoji:
`$form-check-input-checked-bg-image: ✔️;`

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/theming-bootstrap-emoji-checkmark-forked-guk28b (it's a bit slow and you might have to rebuild it from the refresh arrow each time but it should work.)

Comment: You can't, if you look at [the source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/forms/_form-check.scss#L66), the variable is used as a `background-image` value:`background-image: escape-svg($form-check-input-checked-bg-image)`

Comment: Great observation @AmauryHanser.
Based on that new info I managed to insert an emoji in the checkbox with:
```$form-check-input-checked-bg-image:       url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='150px' height='150px' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text x='0' y='130px' font-size='130px' clip-path='url(%23emojiClipPath)'></text></svg>")```

I copied it from here - https://www.bram.us/2021/03/15/css-background-clip-demo-text-with-animated-emoji/ and it seems like it's working. Will further investigate and post a trimmed version of the above code and I think it could be a viable workaround.

Comment: That'sa good idea!